# Rutas en fastapi

Tags: rutas, fastapi

Tengo un archivo main.py para una aplicación fastapi como el siguiente:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from fastapi.openapi.docs import get_redoc_html, get_swagger_ui_html
from classes.queries import *

app = FastAPI()

# Crea un ruteador
router_roles = APIRouter(prefix="/roles", tags=["Roles"])
router_usuarios = APIRouter(prefix="/usuarios", tags=["Usuarios"])
# Agrega los ruteadores a la aplicación principal
app.include_router(router_roles)
app.include_router(router_usuarios)


@app.get("/")
def main():
    return "Bienvenido a Danza Fenix"

@router_roles.get("/roles/listar")
def roles_listar():
    return qw_list_roles()
```

Cuando abro `127.0.0.1:8000/docs` me aparece la primera ruta, la que corresponde a `@app.get("/")`, pero la segunda no me aparece. Por qué?

Comment: /roles/roles/listar?

Comment: Si te refieres a que debería ponerlo como @router_roles.get("/listar") también lo he probado, y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Te da error? ¿No carga? ¿Aparece una página en blanco? ¿Estás colocando la url con o sin "/" al final?